# How to pass the captured image to a different activity to set to the image view in android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, image-capture

I have two Activities first activity has the dynamic image view  and on click i am calling the second activity where camera in invoked to capture a image, now i am able to invoke camera and capture a image but how would i pass that image to the previous activity and set to the image view.

```
String fileName = "testphoto.jpg";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
            "Image capture by camera");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I achieve using two activities with the help of `startActivityForResult`.

check below piece code, hope its helpful you:

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:text="Button" />


     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FirstActivity.java**

*It will open second activity with `startActivityResult`*

```
package com.example.demo_cameraintent;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/testing";

      File xmlDirectory = new File(extStorageDirectory);
        if (!xmlDirectory.exists())
            xmlDirectory.mkdirs();

        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

              String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
              Log.d("*****************", "inside onactivityresult in main activity="+result);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(result);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {



             //Write your code on no result return 

        }
        }//onAcrivityResult


    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

*Here when its called it will directly open `cameraIntent` and within `onActivityResult` it will return back to Firstactivity with your output*

```
package com.example.demo_cameraintent;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    String filepath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

         filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/testing/"+"test.jpg";
        System.out.println("thumbnail path~~~~~~"+filepath);
        File file = new File(filepath);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);


        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 100) {

                 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                 returnIntent.putExtra("result",filepath);
                 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
                 finish();
        }


    }



}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo_cameraintent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.demo_cameraintent.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out but still i am not able to set it.. thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Seem you are trying to capture image from camera and setting on  your view, But I think you don't need two activities to achieve your goal.

You can achieve in single activity with the help of `startActivityForResult`.

Simply call `Camera Intent` on click of imageview, and get back your result within same activity, check below code:

Define path for capture image:

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername/"+filename;
System.out.println("thumbnail path~~~~~~"+filepath);
File file = new File(filepath);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

code this on click of imageview:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

onActivityResult in same activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100) {
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        Bitmap bitmap;
        bitmap=GlobalMethods.decodeFile(_path);//function to decode.
        if (bitmap == null) {
            ivPhy.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } 
        else {
            ivPhy.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            ivPhy.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
    }


}
```

Required permission pass into manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt help, i am having two activites because of the design need, like i am having a layout where i have three buttons one for camera and for gallery so on....thats why need two activities. how could i pass then

Comment: @cavallo for camera action do in the same activity and for gallery use two activities as you need in your design.

Comment: @cavallo yes its possible, on click of image open contextMenu, with option `image from camera` & `image from gallery`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ContentValues` for creating `imageUri`, just store your image in sdcard like this:

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/testphoto.jpg";
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(path)) );
```

After that, while calling second activity just pass the path of file like this:

```
intent.putExtra("pathOfImage",path);
```

Now, on second activity you can just retrieve the image from sdcard:

```
File f = new File(getIntent().getStringExtra("pathOfImage"));
ImageView mImgView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```